# Is this proof of the equivalence of $((\forall x: A(x)) \Rightarrow B) \Leftrightarrow (\exists x: ( A(x) \Rightarrow B) )$ correct?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

I would like to know if the following contraposition proof of the above mentioned equivalence is correct. Thanks in advance.

1 $$((\forall x: A(x)) \Rightarrow B) \Leftrightarrow (\exists x: ( A(x) \Rightarrow B) )$$

2 $$((\forall x: A(x)) \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\exists x: ( A(x) \Rightarrow B) )$$ $$\land$$ $$(\exists : ( A(x) \Rightarrow B) ) \Rightarrow ((\forall x: A(x)) \Rightarrow B)$$

3 Let $$((\forall x: A(x)) \Rightarrow B)\equiv True$$ $$and$$ $$(\exists x: ( A(x) \Rightarrow B) )\equiv False$$

4 $$(\exists : ( A(x) \Rightarrow B) )\equiv False \Rightarrow A(x)\equiv True \land B\equiv False 
\Rightarrow \unicode{x21af} ((\forall x: A(x)) \Rightarrow B)\equiv False $$

5 therefore $$((\forall x: A(x)) \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow (\exists x: ( A(x) \Rightarrow B) )$$

Now for the other way around:

6 Let $$((\forall x: A(x)) \Rightarrow B)\equiv False$$ $$and$$ $$(\exists x: ( A(x) \Rightarrow B) )\equiv True$$

7 $$((\forall x: A(x)) \Rightarrow B)\equiv False \Rightarrow A(x) \equiv True \land B \equiv False \Rightarrow \unicode{x21af} (\exists x: ( A(x) \Rightarrow B) )\equiv False$$

8 therefore $$(\exists x: ( A(x) \Rightarrow B) ) \Rightarrow ((\forall x: A(x)) \Rightarrow B)$$

My concern with this solution is that I incorrectly dealt with the quantifiers in 4th and 7th lines after respectively asserting the truth values of the subparts $A(x)$ and $B$. Apologies for the awkward formatting, I'm still getting the hang of it.

Comment: Your proof is quite informal; thus, its validity depends on some crucial details. The approach is semantical: thus, considering a domain $D$ whatever, you have to be careful in the steps where you manage quantifiers. Step 4: $\exists x (Ax \to B)$ False means that for **every** $d \in D$: $A(x/d)$ True and $B$ False. Now you can introduce the universal quantifier.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you mean that I should specify sets and their subparts for my proof to be more formal, right? 
I'd also really appreciate it if you could recommend me some sort of guide to learn proper proof building and such, I have just begun studying mathematics at university and have little to no clue how to construct proper formal proofs. Thanks by the way!